# navbar not resizing properly when using materializecss

Tags: html, css, materialize

I'm folllowing example on http://materializecss.com/navbar.html, my code is like this:

```html
<div class="navbar-fixed">
                    <nav>
                        <div class="nav-wrapper">
                            <a href="#!" class="brand-logo center">Logo</a>
                            <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
                            <ul class="left">
                                <li><a href="sass.html">About Us</a></li>
                                <li><a href="badges.html">Services</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul class="right">
                                <li><a href="sass.html">Testimonials</a></li>
                                <li><a href="badges.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                            </ul>

                            <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
                                <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
                                <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
                                <li><a href="collapsible.html">Javascript</a></li>
                                <li><a href="mobile.html">Mobile</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                </div>
```

Which looks like this:[image: fullpage screen capture]
But when window/webpage is made smaller, the navigation content is messed up, like this:
[image: reduce nav image]
what could I be doing wrong? Please help

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="navbar-fixed">
<nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <a href="#!" class="brand-logo center">Logo</a>
        <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
        <ul class="left hide-on-med-and-down">
            <li><a href="sass.html">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="badges.html">Services</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
            <li><a href="sass.html">Testimonials</a></li>
            <li><a href="badges.html">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
            <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
            <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
            <li><a href="collapsible.html">Javascript</a></li>
            <li><a href="mobile.html">Mobile</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: just add the class on hide-on-med-and-down. Now it will fine on mobile. if not add css code too. if menu icon is not display check path of material icon.

Answer (score 0):

```
<nav>
<div class="nav-wrapper">
  <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
  <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
  <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
    <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
    <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
    <li><a href="collapsible.html">Javascript</a></li>
    <li><a href="mobile.html">Mobile</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
    <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
    <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
    <li><a href="collapsible.html">Javascript</a></li>
    <li><a href="mobile.html">Mobile</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: you need to add two nav code one for mobile and other one for large screens.

Comment: But this was their code example if you follow my link.Could you please explain to me in more detail please. Your code works but mine doesn't but I can't see why